# How to disable encryption when using JDBC to connect to SQL server with TLSv1?

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc

There's an old SQL server running TLS 1.0 that I need to connect to

When I'm using `sqlcmd` I'm able to connect to it by skipping TLS with `-N disable` flag

But when attempting to connect using JDBC, I'm setting `encrypt=false` but it doesn't help, the connection still fails because `TLS10` is not supported and only `TLS12,TLS13` may be used.

How do I force the JDBC connection to disable encryption via DSN?

Comment: If you don't want it secure why use TLS at all? And conversely, what is your objection to encryption?

Comment: No objection at all, but I can't seem to skip the handshake

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try like this

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://yourServer:1433;databaseName=yourDatabase;user=yourUsername;password=yourPassword;encrypt=false;sslProtocol=TLSv1";
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help, TLSv1 seems to be unavailable completely

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

- Create a copy of the JDK's `java.security` file, name it `java_tlsv1.security`
- In `java_tlsv1.security` file edit the following:

  - In `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` remove `TLSv1`
  - Set `crypto.policy` to `unlimited`
  - Edit all of the `security.provider.tbd` keys and number them, e.g: `security.provider.tbd=SUN -> security.provider.1=SUN`, `security.provider.tbd=SunRsaSign -> security.provider.2=SunRsaSign` etc
- Run your app with `-Djava.security.properties=java_tlsv1.security`